# need to compare data in two excel files

Tags: excel, etl, vlookup

I need to compare two excel files. One is extracted from database and saved as CSV. Other file is cumulative report containing all records for that day. I need to check if all the data in the cumulative report is in my other csv file that's extracted from database. I know `VLOOKUP`, but I am not sure if VLOOKUP can compare entire file records. Many files have 4 to 5 thousand records with 50 columns in it. Is there any other option? Any free `ETL` tools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use beyond compare tool to compare two files.

- Sort both files on an ID field
- And compare them using *Beyond Compare* tool

It's a nice tool. You can get it [HERE](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use `VLOOKUP`.

A simple way to solve this is to

**1.** Create a database connection for the CSV saved data in Sheet1.

**2.** Copy and Link the second file (cumulative report) to this file in Sheet2.

Then use `VLOOKUP` or simple `IF statements` to compare the data.